IIS Rewrite rule to rewrite to a static page without changing url
I have an application https://customer.com/ax/xyz, when this url is hit it should point to a static page without changing the url.
the problem is when i hit the url https://customer.com/ax/xyz, it redirects to https://customer.com/staticpage but i do not want the url to change
I have setup an application called "staticpage" which displays index.html and there is a rewrite rule in IIS which displays index.html
rewrite rule details action

First of all, you need to understand the difference between a redirect and a rewrite.
A redirect is a client-side request to have the web browser go to another URL. This means that the URL that you see in the browser will update to the new URL.
A rewrite is a server-side rewrite of the URL before it’s fully processed by IIS. This will not change what you see in the browser because the changes are hidden from the user.
So set your action to rewrite in IIS as shown in the picture below


i am using the rewrite action itself.. i have attached 2 images of my rule in the question
